# Bootstrap Navbar Unexpected Bottom Spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This has been asked several times.  I've checked several different answers, and found no resolution in any of them.  I've set `margin-bottom: 0` for the navbar.  I'm not using the fixed-top navbar.  My HTML tags are all closed.  None of the resolution in the questions I've seen have helped.

The MCVE for this is super simple.  I feel like the answer must be as well, but this is my first experience with bootstrap, and I don't see it.  Here's a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/vIFYkRbrJr#).  For completeness, I'll copy the material here.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li onclick="navigateToSettings()" id="settingsHeaderItem"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Content Pane -->
<div id="contentPane" class="contentPane">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.contentPane {
  background-color: black;
}
```

**RESULT**

[image: Spacing]

Answer (score 2):

Your **h1** and **nav** has margins... and also use a class so it does not affect every other h1 and nav tags.

```
h1.someclass {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
nav.someclass {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/eVIT3PIaJb

Comment: Christ's sake I'm going to bed (once it lets me accept this).  Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Set `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%` to `.contentPane` css class. This will make the container to take the height of the child.

http://www.bootply.com/nsERfrADNA

Answer (score 0):

You can try It :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
```